# Defining custom icon for points in L.geoJSON within fetch call

Tags: leaflet, geojson, markers, icon

I am trying to define a new icon for my points in Leaflet but am drawing a blank. I am using Fetch (see code) to access the data and have it displayed with the default icon but can't work out how to change it to another within the fetch. Thanks.

```
    let puburl = "http:...
    let pubIcon = new L.icon({
      iconUrl: 'markers/beer.png'
    });

    fetch(puburl)
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(data) {
            L.geoJSON(data, {
                onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
                    layer.bindPopup("<a href='" + feature.properties.URL + "'>" + feature.properties.PubName + "</a>")
                }
            }).addTo(map);
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify [`pointToLayer`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#geojson-pointtolayer) in the `L.geoJSON` call:

> A Function defining how GeoJSON points spawn Leaflet layers. It is internally called when data is added, passing the GeoJSON point feature and its LatLng. The default is to spawn a default Marker:
>
> ```
> function(geoJsonPoint, latlng) {
>     return L.marker(latlng);
> }
> ```

In your case it would look like this:

```
L.geoJSON(data, {
  onEachFeature: {...},
  pointToLayer: function(point, latlng) {
    return L.marker(latlng, { icon: pubIcon })
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan, very much appreciated.